# Converting an .ai file with multiple artboard into a single .svg file

Tags: adobe-illustrator, icon, svg, ttf

I am trying to convert an .ai file having multiple artboard into a single .svg file in order to generate a single .ttf file having all the icons.

I have **tried deselecting use artboards option** which does give a single svg file but when viewed, only one artwork appears.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as no artboard for the exporter. Make one more artboard that encompasses all your art then export only that artboard. Do the following:

- Enable aboard tool and draw a new aboard around all your objects, or use the fit artwork bounds option.
- Then export with art boards option on but specifying only the last art board number in the range

Comment: Issue still persists as the generated ttf file when viewed in birdfont shows one glyph containing all the icons rather then having different glyphs for each individual icon.

Comment: @AbhishekDwivedi But that has nothing to do with export its how birdfont reads the data one file one icon. Theres nothing you can do about this in illustrators end except save many files. Easiest would be to copypaste though

Comment: Thanks Joojaa. I thought this might be a limitation but then i accessed icon svg file from [link](http://ionicons.com/) and it works perfectly for ttf conversion. Could you please highlight the difference between a general svg and svg from \ionicons-2.0.1\ionicons-2.0.1\fonts\ionicons.svg